# DRY - How to make 2 GET functions that takes different tables into 1 GET function

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, dry

In my REST API i have nearly 2 nearly identical functions. How to make it 1 that is changing based on what i pass in url?

```
app.delete('/tourists/:id', (req, res, next) => {
   pool.connect(function (err, client, done) {
       if (err) {
           console.log("Cannot connect to the DB" + err);
       }
       client.query('DELETE FROM tourists WHERE tourists.id=' + req.params.id, function (err, result) {
            done();
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(400).send(err);
            }
            client.query('SELECT * FROM tourists', function (err, result) {done();res.status(200).send(result.rows)});
       })
   })
});
app.delete('/flights/:id', (req, res, next) => {
   pool.connect(function (err, client, done) {
       if (err) {
           console.log("Cannot connect to the DB" + err);
       }
       client.query('DELETE FROM flights WHERE flights.id=' + req.params.id, function (err, result) {
            done();
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(400).send(err);
            }
            client.query('SELECT * FROM flights', function (err, result) {done();res.status(200).send(result.rows)});
       })
   })
});
```

I TRIED with

```
app.get('/:table/:id' , ...

// client.query('DELETE FROM ' + req.params.table + '...
```

And i tried with

```
req.params.name
```

But both are wrong

Answer (score 3):

> I wonder why the other answer was deleted by its author - that seemed to be even DRYer!!

Not exactly what you want, but it's DRY

Create a function

```
const mydeletefn = table => (req, res, next) => {
   pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
       if (err) {
           console.log("Cannot connect to the DB" + err);
       }
       client.query(`DELETE FROM ${table} WHERE ${table}.id=${req.params.id}`, (err, result) => {
            done();
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(400).send(err);
            }
            client.query(`SELECT * FROM ${table}`, (err, result) => {
                done();
                res.status(200).send(result.rows)
            });
       })
   })
};
```

now use it like

```
app.delete('/tourists/:id', mydeletefn('tourists'));
app.delete('/flights/:id', mydeletefn('flights'));
```

Another perhaps more useful option:

```
const mydeletefn = (table, col='id') => (req, res, next) => {
   pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
       if (err) {
           console.log("Cannot connect to the DB" + err);
       }
       client.query(`DELETE FROM ${table} WHERE ${table}.${col}=${req.params[col]}`, (err, result) => {
            done();
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(400).send(err);
            }
            client.query(`SELECT * FROM ${table}`, (err, result) => {
                done();
                res.status(200).send(result.rows)
            });
       })
   })
};
```

The difference being that you can specify what the parameter/column to use as an index is ... (it defaults to id)

e.g., if you had a table and you wanted to delete by column name 'userid' instead of 'id'

```
app.delete('/users/:userid', mydeletefn('users', 'userid'));
```

and finally - I don't know why @SimpleJ delete his answer. combining the above code with his

```
const deleteEndpoint = (table, col='id') => 
    app.delete(`/${table}/:${col}`, (req, res, next) => {
        pool.connect(function (err, client, done) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Cannot connect to the DB" + err);
            }
            client.query(`DELETE FROM ${table} WHERE ${table}.${col}=${req.params[col]}`, (err, result) => {
                done();
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.status(400).send(err);
                }
                client.query(`SELECT * FROM ${table}`, (err, result) => {
                    done();
                    res.status(200).send(result.rows);
                });
            })
        })
    };
```

Then it's a simple case of

```
deleteEndpoint('tourists'); // col defaults to `id`
deleteEndpoint('flights'); // col defaults to `id`
deleteEndpoint('users', 'userid');
```